# Wordpress doesn't select page template for parent pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a WP Theme and I'm having this issue that's driving me crazy...

For every single (parent) page I create, WP chooses `index.php` as template. I'm aware of WP template hierarchy but it doesn't matter if I use `page.php`, `page-$slug.php` or `page-$id.php`, I've also tried using:

```
<?php
  /*
  Template Name: My Template 
  */
?>
```

and assigning the page this template in the Editor.

I've also hooked, for debugging purposes, `template_include` as follows:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'check_template_selection', 99 );

function check_template_selection( $template ) {
    global $post;
    echo "Post ID: " . $post->ID . "<br/>";
    echo "Template File:" . $template . "<br/>";
    echo is_page() ? "YES" : "NO";
    return $template;
}
```

And for every page URL I check (for example: `http://example.com/mypage`) I'm getting:

> Post ID:
>
> Template File:/nfs/c11/h05/mnt/205383/domains/*example.com*/html/wp-content/themes/*mytheme*/index.php
>
> NO

I've tried deleting the pages and creating them again, but it's the same. The fact is it works fine for child pages. For example: `http://example.com/mypage/mychildpage` shows:

> Post ID:589
>
> Template File:/nfs/c11/h05/mnt/205383/domains/*example.com*/html/wp-content/themes/*mytheme*/page-mychildpage.php
>
> YES

I'm using WP 4.4.2, ACF PRO 5.3.6.1, Custom Post Type UI 1.2.4 and Instagram Feed Pro Personal 2.0.4.1. No other plugins. Anyway, I tried unsuccessfully to desactivate them all. I've developed the theme from scratch and I've done dozens of themes before and I've never experienced this issue before...

This is my `.htaccess` and my permalinks are properly configured as `/%postname%/`, no category base.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So please, any advice or hint on what am I missing here would be very apreciated. Thank you guys!

---

### Edit:

After hours of deep search (Thank you so much John Blackbourn for your [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin) I found that my parent pages match the wrong rewrite rule, so now I guess it's something about rewrite rules priority.

**Wrong match for a parent page URL:** `http://example.com/about`

[image: Wrong Match]
[image: Wrong Rule Selected]

**Right match for a child page URL:** `http://example.com/about/about-child`

[image: Right Match]
[image: Right Rule Selected]

Comment: Keep in mind that WP **may load index.php** when it's a 404 error.  **are you sure** that the page slug(s) exist properly? Additionally, I'd recommend going to permalinks and clicking "Save" (this forces WP to update the permalink structure, which often solves a HUGE percentage of this kind of problem).

Comment: Yes, I've checked and re-checked the slugs, I've created test pages too. And I've saved permalinks multiple times (as you said, this usually works) and I've checked that my .htaccess is working too... But nothing... Thank you for your hints @cale_b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a few years later, but I ran into an almost identical problem. Using the [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin as you did also helped me figure it out.

What I had did earlier today was make a custom taxonomy named `year`. The idea was to group my posts—which are now vehicles for my client's site—by the year the vehicle was manufactured.

However, like you, when I went to any top level page I was directed to the `index.php` template file instead of the `page.php` template file.

By using the Query Monitor plugin, I saw that I was getting the exact same results as you. My matched query was `year=about`.

I removed my custom `year` taxonomy and then refreshed my permalinks by saving them through the WordPress admin `Settings > Permalinks` and voila, my top level pages are now going to the correct `page.php` template file.

Comment: Thank you Jeslen! As they say, it's never too late! Honestly, I don't even remember how I managed to solve this, but your answer sure might help others in the same situation.